# curl with POST not working, request.POST is empty

Tags: python, json, django, curl

I'm attempting to send a post request with some json data using:

```
curl --verbose -X POST -d @testfile.json http://oururl.com/someapi --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

the view on the other end reads `request.POST.dict()` -- but `request.POST` is showing up empty (though content length is getting set)! I've used this method before and never had this happen, can't figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're posting JSON. `request.POST` is for form-encoded data.

You should be accessing `request.body` and passing it through `json.loads()`.

Comment: I tried to get fancy with it. For anyone else with this problem, you can still use the above method, just remove the --header (defaults to form data encoding) and alter the file structure to look like `things=[{"id":5,"column":"foo"}]
&lang=en_US
&user_country=US`